# Unnest dataframe whose values in rows have mixed type values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working with a dataframe in `R` using `tidyverse`. I need to unnest it because it contains rows stored as dataframes. My dataframe `ex` is next (included as `dput`):

```
ex
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name1 values      
  <chr> <list>      
1 A     <df [3 x 2]>
2 B     <df [4 x 2]>
```

It is actually a tibble. In order to unnest I use next code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
ex2 <- ex %>%  
  tidyr::unnest(c(values), .drop = TRUE)
```

Which returns next error:

```
Error:
! Can't combine `..1$value` <character> and `..2$value` <integer>.
```

The issue is that some columns in the nested dataframe are character and other integer. So I believed using `as.character()` would help but it did not worked.

How can I unnest this tibble? Many thanks!

Data is next:

```
#Data
ex <- structure(list(name1 = c("A", "B"), values = list(structure(list(
    value = c("Home", "Draw", "Away"), odd = c("1.58", "3.75", 
    "6.50")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), structure(list(
    value = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 0L), odd = c("7.77", "29.34", "2.80", 
    "1.92")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L)))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main trick to obtain the desired output is to cycle over each row of the tibble to transform the first column of each nested list into character. Probably, there's a shorter way to do it, but here's a solution using the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ex2 <- ex |> 
  # Mutate across values column, map over each row
  mutate(across(values, ~ map(1:nrow(ex), ~ ex |> 
                                # Select values column
                                select(values) |>
                                # Get lists out of the tibble
                                magrittr::extract2(1) |> 
                                # Get .x entry of the lists
                                magrittr::extract2(.x) |> 
                                # mutate across value to turn it into character
                                mutate(across(value, as.character))))) %>%
  unnest(c(values))

## A tibble: 7 × 3
#  name1 value odd  
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A     Home  1.58 
#2 A     Draw  3.75 
#3 A     Away  6.50 
#4 B     2     7.77 
#5 B     3     29.34
#6 B     1     2.80 
#7 B     0     1.92
```

Comment: Many thanks sir. Lets wait a few if other answer is replied! Kind regards! I have upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

First splitting by group is one option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

group_split(ex, name1)[[1]] %>% 
  unnest(values) %>% 
  bind_rows(group_split(ex, name1)[[2]] %>% 
  unnest(values) %>% 
  mutate(value = as.character(value)))
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  name1 value odd
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     Home  1.58
2 A     Draw  3.75
3 A     Away  6.50
4 B     2     7.77
5 B     3     29.34
6 B     1     2.80
7 B     0     1.92
```

With **base R**

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(ex$name1), function(x) 
  cbind(name1 = ex$name1[x], ex$values[[x]])))
  name1 value   odd
1     A  Home  1.58
2     A  Draw  3.75
3     A  Away  6.50
4     B     2  7.77
5     B     3 29.34
6     B     1  2.80
7     B     0  1.92
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option - where you lapply over the values list and modify the columns to be character. Then you can unnest it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

ex$values = lapply(ex$values, function(v) {
  modify(v, as.character)
})
  
ex %>%
  unnest(values)
```

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  name1 value odd  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     Home  1.58 
2 A     Draw  3.75 
3 A     Away  6.50 
4 B     2     7.77 
5 B     3     29.34
6 B     1     2.80 
7 B     0     1.92
```